# Laravel custom rule required_if and required_without

Tags: laravel, validation

is there a possibility to make a rule for validate an input array like this:

```
'agent_id.*' =>'nullable|required_with:commission.*|required_with:remuneration.*|integer|exists:agents,id',
'commission.*' => ['nullable', 'regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/i', new DocumentFTVDetailCommissionOrRemunerationRule()],
'remuneration.*' => ['nullable', 'regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/i', new DocumentFTVDetailRemunerationOrCommissionRule()],
```

-agent_id.* is required with commission.* or remuneration.*

-commission.* is required if there is agent_id.* and remuneration.* is empy or not set

-remuneration.* is required if there is agent_id.* and commission.* is empy or not set

DocumentFTVDetailCommissionOrRemunerationRule() and DocumentFTVDetailRemunerationOrCommissionRule() are the rules that limit the choose at one between commission.* or remuneration.*

Thank you

Comment: You can use `Validator::extend()` to make your own rules: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a [Custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Start by generating the rule class:

```
php artisan make:rule DocumentFTVDetailCommissionOrRemunerationRule
php artisan make:rule DocumentFTVDetailRemunerationOrCommissionRule
```

Then modify these classes to apply the logic as shown in the documentation - for instance, here's an example of the Password validation rule I've created for my own system:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Password implements Rule
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    const PATTERN = '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@#$!%*?&]{8,30}$/';

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
    {
        return preg_match(self::PATTERN, $value) === 1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message(): string
    {
        return 'Invalid password format';
    }
}
```